# How to add multiple files in git

Tags: git, ubuntu, terminal, git-add

I have 4 files in a folder. I have modified 3 of them. How do I add and push only the modified  files all at once. Will "git add ." work here.

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can also use 'git add -i' to get an interactive shell where you can stage/unstage files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

Answer (score 3):

1) You can add only the three modified files with:

```
git add file1 file2 file3
```

2) OR You can add all the files with

```
git add .
```

3) OR If they are all of the same type and say, the fourth one has a different extension, then you can also add the three files using:

```
git add *.js   //example for files with Javascript .js extension
```

Then do : `git commit -m "message"`
and then a : `git push`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Yes in that case you can simply use `git add .`. You can check which files have been modified by using `git status`. If only *your* three files are being displayed, a simple `git add .` is enough, afterwards use `git push`.

Comment: As the fourth file *didn't* change, `git add .` is *exactly* what he wants.

Comment: BTW, it ain't a regex, it is a glob pattern. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`git add -A` stages All;

`git add .` stages new and modified, without deleted;

`git add -u` stages modified and deleted, without new.